# fragment update text on change

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

So I have a fragment that I need to be able to always update the text.

The text fields are:

- Song
- Artist

In my MainActivity I have a http request that keeps ping the server and getting the latest information.

That updates a global Class

```
package com.drn1.drn1

object DataHolder {
    private var Song = ""
    fun set_Song(s: String) {
        Song = s
    }

    fun get_Song(): String {
        return Song
    }

private var Artist = ""
    fun set_Artist(s: String) {
        Song = s
    }

    fun get_Artist(): String {
        return Artist
    }

    private var MDIA = "http://stream.radiomedia.com.au:8003/stream"
    fun set_Media(s: String) {
        MDIA = s
    }

    fun get_Media(): String {
        return MDIA
    }


}
```

The issue is I can't re-set the text in the fragment

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        //val context = inflater.context
        //binding = MplayerBinding.inflate(com.drn1.drn1.R.layout.fragment_mplayer)



        val root: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mplayer, container, false)
        val btn = root.findViewById(R.id.mPlayPP) as ImageButton
        val SG = root.findViewById(R.id.song) as TextView

        SG.setText(Song)
}
```

Wondering what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: You should not make an HTTP request every time to keep updated data that's an overkill of resources that's [Polling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_(computer_science)) . you need some Connection oriented approach to do it may be a Socket.

Comment: @ADM will look into this, but that does not solve the question of how I update the textView in a fragment

Comment: @RussellHarrower Take a look in to using LiveData with the repository pattern, the official google training resources cover it well

Comment: You have to put this line "SG.setText(Song)" in the response of http request you called and delcare  the "SG"  textView globally.

Answer (score 1):

`onCreateView()` is only run the first time the Activity is created.

It is not clear on your code where you are updating the `DataHolder`, however wherever you do it, you need to then call a method in your Activity to update the text view with the latest data.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Ryan, `onCreateView()` will get called only once. So You will need a class-level variable for song textview.(In your case make `SG` class level variable instead of local variable).

Then create a method to update the song text

```
fun updateSong(song: String) {
    SG.setText(Song)
}
```

At last, You have to call this method of fragment, Whenever you get the updated information.

In `MainActivity`, when You get the updated information, You will have an instance of this fragment. So you can call this method on that object